# $(input).blur() & $(input).focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur, focusout

I have the next html form:

```
<form role="form" action="MAILTO:alejandro@distal.com.ar " method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="form-contacto"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div id="form-column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-push-3 col-md-push-3 col-lg-push-3">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="sr-only">Nombre:</label>
      <input type="textbox" placeholder="ingrese su nombre" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
      <div id="nameRequiredError" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">El nombre es obligatorio.</div>
      <div id="nameFormatError" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Solo se permiten letras y puntos.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="sr-only">Correo electr&oacute;nico</label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="ingrese su correo electr&oacute;nico" name="name" id="email" class="form-control">
      <div id="emailRequiredError" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">El direcci&oacute;n de correo electr&oacute;nico es obligatoria.</div>
      <div id="emailFormatError" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Ingrese un correo electr&oacute;nico v&aacute;lido.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="sr-only"></label>
      <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje..." sizable="false"></textarea>
      <div id="messageRequiredError" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Ingrese un mensaje para enviar.</div>
      <div id="messageFormatError" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">El mensaje no tiene nig&uacute;n caracter alfanum&eactue;rico.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="form-column" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-push-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-push-6">
      <submit class="btn btn-primary form-control"> Enviar &gt;&gt; </submit>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to validate the data entry when the input loose focus, but i haven't catch the focus out. I tried all this:

```
$('#name').blur(function(event) {
    alert("blur");
});

$('#name').focusout(function(event) {
    alert("focusout");
});

// $('#name').live('focusout', function(){
//  alert("live(focusout)");
// });

// $('#name').live('blur', function(){
//  alert("live(blur)");
// });

$('#name').trigger('focusout', function(){
    alert("trigger(focusout)");
});

$('#name').trigger('blur', function(){
    alert("trigger(blur)");
});

$('#name').on('focusout', function(){
    alert("on(focusout)");
});

$('#name').on('blur', function(){
    alert("on(blur)");
});
```

but these don't work, any know why? I'm turned crazy!
thanks for everyone that will read this!

Comment: have you wrapped js at above in jquery ready function $(function(){ -js-here- })?

Comment: Maybe you should wrap it inside $(document).ready like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7thammd/

Comment: Do you know what `trigger` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to work fine in JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dfkg7dha/2/

But try adding the event handler inside the `ready` function. Code inside here will ony run once the DOM is ready for JavaScript to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#name').blur(function(event) {
        alert("blur: perform validation here");
    });
});
```

and also for sanity make sure the JQuery JavaScript has been referenced on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/znty7yoy/1/
```

All you have here should work, but I think you're missing one thing - DOM is not ready before you're trying to query it.

Check the fiddle - if script before HTML - this won't work, if after - it will.

To prevent such cases just wrap with:

```
$(function () {
   $('#name')....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jquery you can do it like this:

```
var nameEl = document.getElementById("name");

nameEl.addEventListener("blur", function(){
  alert("blurry");
});
```

Link to the code: http://codepen.io/sp90/pen/RWpXBQ